# how to periodically run sql query in azure?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I know some jobs can be run periodically or querys a database. how achievement run this code every "x" days in an azure sql table?

```
DELETE FROM [MobileServiceExtra].[ACTIVITY]
WHERE [NewsItemDate] < GETDATE()- 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Windows Azure Scheduler is a new service that has just gone into preview - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/scheduler/. This looks like an all-purpose service to do this kind of thing. I don't expect SQL on Azure will ever support Agent.

Comment: Everything I have read about Azure suggests this is true; SQL Azure != SQL Server, and so things like the Agents are indeed missing - just means you have to find a workaround in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that Azure [does not support SQL Server Agent and scheduling of jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#sqlagent).

According to a series of blog posts on MSDN you can however use the Windows Azure Worker role to schedule custom jobs (that run SQL):

[I Miss You SQL Server Agent: Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/30/10044271.aspx)

I haven't tried this, so I can't tell you if it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) within our Azure combined web and worker role.

You can see my colleagues post about it [here](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/07/quartz-net-in-azure-with-autofac-smoothness/)

Comment: Use Windows Azure Scheduler instead of Quartz.

Comment: Quartz has features that Azure scheduler doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Mobile Services. Mobile Services comes with a Scheduler which can connect to your database and do whatever you need in a recurring schedule.

More information:
[Build your own SQL Server Agent for Windows Azure SQL Database with the Scheduler](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/build-your-own-sql-server-agent-for-windows-azure-sql-database-with-the-scheduler/)

You would end up writing a little bit of javascript in the Scheduler which will run your SQL statement:

```
function Call_sp_ClearOldLogs() {
    console.log("Executing sp_ClearOldLogs...");
    mssql.query('EXEC dbo.sp_ClearOldLogs', {
        success: function(results) {
        console.log("Finished executing sp_ClearOldLogs.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The mobile services scheduled tasks utilise the Windows Azure Scheduler (see next post).  Good answer though :).

Comment: Where do you get your info that the Mobile Services Scheduler uses the Windows Azure Scheduler? The FAQ clearly states that these are independent from each other: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/scheduler/

Comment: See the second point on this page: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Comment: Oh, you got me. Didn't see that one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows azure scheduler preview right now http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/scheduler/.

Do check out the pricing,right now they are charging $10/month and it will be increased to $20/month once the preview period is over.

You can also try aditi scheduler http://www.aditicloud.com/ as well,the only issue with aditi scheduler is its available in azure store ( which is not accessible in many countries) and you have to use your credit card again to consume it.

Hope it helps!

Thanks.

Mohit Chhabra

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a service for this, we offer [this functionality within our Cotega service](http://cotega.com/docs/sql_azure_scheduled_job).  The way that it works is that you create a stored procedure within your database to execute this code and simply set up a schedule for how often you want it to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Automation Runbook. Example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10e933c7-fbd3-42d6-b179-df890cf5f69c/query-a-sql-table-using-azure-automation-runbook?forum=ssdsgetstarted). I use this for daily table truncation, works perfect for me.